# Difference between what is caught as a group in regex101 and in python code

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to catch one before last file extension for example:
file.bin.txt.log => should give me back: `.txt`

My regex value is: `.+(\.\w+)\.\w+`
If you will try it in [regex101](https://regex101.com) you will succeed, but my code give me the whole file path => file.bin.txt.log

file_path source is from a dictionary and appears in debugger like this:

```
file_path = {unicode} u'file.bin.txt.log'
```

My code for fetching the relevant info is:

```
extension = re.match(r'.+(\.\w+)\.\w+',file_path).group()
print extension
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`match.group(n)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MatchObject.group) returns the *single* group number `n`. By convention, the 0th group is always the *full matched string*, so in your case the full file name.

But what you want to get is the captured group with the index 1, so just specify that:

```
>>> re.match('.+(\.\w+)\.\w+', file_path).group(1)
'.txt'
```

Answer (score 2):

Fetch group 1. `group()` by default prints all the matched characters where `group(1)` refers those chars which are captured by group index 1.

```
extension = re.match(r'.+(\.\w+)\.\w+',file_path).group(1)
```

Answer (score 2):

That's because of that `group()` returns the whole match. Instead you need `group(1)` :

```
>>> extension = re.match(r'.+(\.\w+)\.\w+',file_path).group(1)
>>> extension
u'.txt'
```

Also note that you don't have to use regex for such tasks you could simply split your text with dot and get the expected part:

```
>>> file_path.split('.')[-2]
u'txt'
```

Comment: Note that OP actually wants to match the second-to-last extension.